# Is there a synonym for "thesaurus"?

Tags: synonyms

It has always bothered me that there seemed to be this oversight; There is a definition of "dictionary" in a dictionary but no synonym of "thesaurus" in a thesaurus. The best I could figure would be to coin something like "synonympendium", as in a compendium of synonyms. Is anyone aware of a word that would fill this niche?

Comment: What's wrong with "thesaurus"?

Comment: Not that there is anything wrong exactly, it just seemed like a odd oversight. A book that knows other names for everything but its self. There are synonyms for any number of things that are superfluous, why not for the very tome in question?

Comment: Why not use a dictionary to see the meaning of _thesaurus_? It's widely acceped as a book of synonyms and antonyms.

Comment: it is not a matter of definition.  It is a question of specialization: Is there no other word for a book of synonyms than thesaurus. language offers us synonyms for a reason and why shouldn't this boon like wise be extended I ask you. If you feel it is unneeded, fine but is it out there all the same.

Comment: Not every word has a synonym. And specific words like thesaurus don't really need one.  I doubt there is a synoym for _dictionary_ also.

Comment: Actually, if you say "Roget's" most people (who know what a thesaurus is) will know what you mean.

Comment: There's a definition of thesaurus in a dictionary, and there's a synonym of dictionary in a thesaurus. I think that's as far as the etiquette needs to go. Don't you think it's a bit vain of dictionaries to define themselves?

Comment: You could say dictionary of synonyms.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's founded on a false premise. Lots of thesauruses have entries for 'thesaurus'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Thesaurus*** has an interesting history. It actually means a "treasury", or "storehouse of knowledge".

Its earliest reference in the OED is from  *1565   T. Cooper (title)    Thesaurus Linguæ Romanæ et Britannicæ [etc.]*.

The first recorded use of the term to describe a book of synonyms is from 1852 when *Roget's Thesaurus* was published.

I have seen some suggestions of synonyms, such as *wordfinder* and *synonymy* - the latter marked as "rare".

Answer (score 3):

In fact Thesaurus.com *does* list [synonyms for thesaurus.](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/thesaurus?s=t)

It occurs to me to ask a similar question: Why are there no precise synonyms for 'synonym'?

Comment: "onomasticon" is the closest thing listed in your link and it isn't a synonym.

Answer (score 0):

The OED has a citation of **synonymicon** from the 19th century.